# Angularjs loading image

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have used a loading image in my application which will fire when i move from one page to another if the next page takes some time to load

here is my css

```css
.divWaiting {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  opacity: 0.8;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20%;
}
```

Now i have a click event for which it will fire

```
$scope.progress = false; //false by default within the controller but making it true inside

$scope.openFloorChartDetails = function (_building, _floorchart) {
    $scope.progress = true;
    $location.path(rootDir + 'floorChartDetails/' + projverservice.Id + '/' + _building.buildingId + '/' + _floorchart.floorChartId);       
}
```

and in the concerned html page am calling it like this:

```
<div class="divWaiting" ng-show="progress">
    <div>
        <img ng-src="{{rootDIR+'CustomScripts/image/3.gif'}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

It is working fine when for the first time am clicking, the image is coming. But from the next time the page is getting loaded just like that without the image coming.
Am not getting what the problem is

Comment: Check whether progress is set to true when you are clicking the button the next time. May be using {{ progress }}

Comment: Also, is the `<div class="divWaiting" ng-show="progress" />` element still existing after loading another view? Or is it part of the destroyed view? It really show never go away, because you never set `$scope.progress = false` anywhere.